# Install old version of R on Windows 10

Tags: r

How do I install an old version of R on a window 10 64 PC.

I am currently running R 3.2.3 with RStudio without any problems.   However a package I want to use (GSIF) only works on R2.15.  I have found that it is possible to easily get RStudio to work with different R versions and I have found and downloaded the old version of R I want ( R-2.15.1-w.tar.gz) from the CRAN archives.   My problems is cannot work out how to install the R-2.15.1-w.tar.gz package on a windows machine or in fact even if it is the right package for windows.  All the instruction I can find seem to relate to Linux.

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use this link: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/2.15.0/

You can decide Windows RStudio -> Global Options which R version you want to use.

Comment: @J_F the link you attached no longer works.

Comment: @Hector So use this one ;-) 
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hold down the Control key during the launch of RStudio you can cause the R version selection dialog to display at startup.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R